# Registration Successful or Registered Successfully

Tags: word-choice

On my website, I allow the user to create an account, when account has been created through an online form, which sentence below make the most sense to use?

> Registration Successful

or

> Registered Successfully

Comment: I would go with "Registration successful".

Comment: Ishwar, these are not questions for this site.

Comment: @AndrewLeach   thanks i will not use this site to post new questions next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these is ideal. The concept of *registration* involves adding data to a register, where it can be looked up later. In many cases, however, the specific register is not identified.

Depending on the design of your system and its messaging overall, **registered successfully** would likely be the better choice.

Most systems of the type you describe have an internal architecture defined in terms of *states* and *transitions*.

In principle, the user can get to the “registered” state in more than one way. Perhaps they followed a sequence of pages viewed with a web browser. Perhaps they clicked on a link in a message of some kind. The important information (for them or anyone attempting to help them) is that they are now registered.

In contrast, *registration successful* indicates that the process of moving from an unregistered state to the registered state has been completed. However, if there is more than one way to do this, you may need to define a separate message for each way, or put yourself in a situation where a single message is used for multiple ways.

A system interface can be “state-like” or “process-like” in the wayfinding information it presents. The important thing is to be consistent. However, you will let yourself in for less trouble down the road if you use states. The number of possible transitions grows more rapidly than the number of states. Think of the *future you* and make that person’s life a little easier.